# can't reference the xml layout in Activity

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity, setcontentview

I'm facing a problem in which I set content view of my created activity.xml but it's showing some error. Please help me, I'm still learning.

this is the image while creating the activity
[image: this is the image while creating the activity]

this the image which shows the error
[image: this the image which shows the error]

and this the xml file
activity_daily_expense_fragment_handler.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".daily_expense_fragment_handler">

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Pls check your imported R.

Comment: Hi. Do not share screenshot but error messages please

Comment: Can you pls send the pic of import R. Have you imported with android.R ? If yes then import with your package name

Comment: thank you i didnt imported R i have enter now thank you  all

Comment: If it's working then can you pls accept my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pls check your imported R ? If you've imported with android.R then import with your package name.

Answer (score 0):

First you should create the name of the class with uppercase letter like : `DailyExpenseFragmentHandler`

Then after it check your imports. Remove your R.imported file, and click on the layout then after it press `ALT + Enter` to create it automatically.